# Android notification tray does not collapse after clicking ongoing notification

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview

When clicking an ongoing event having remoteview with various butons, the activity loads up in the backgound and the notification tray does not collapse.

I am getting this problem only on ICS 4.0. It works fine on 4.1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following two code line to collapse the notification bar.

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(it);
```